# Is there a way to keep 'select' options open for screenshots?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, screenshot, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to take screenshots of a site and need to keep a 'select' menu-open so that I can capture its contents. It always closes before taking the screenshot.

I've tried taking a screenshot after clicking on the menu

```
test('SelectOptionsScreenshot', async t => {
    await faveDogs.load(t)
    await t
        .click(faveDogs.dogSelect)
        .takeScreenshot()
```

I've tried it by telling it to look for 'options' with no specific text

```
test('SelectOptionsScreenshot', async t => {
    await faveDogs.load(t)
    await t
        .click(faveDogs.dogSelect)
        .click(faveDogs.dogSelect.find('option')
        .takeScreenshot()
```

I've tried having it hover over an option

```
test('SelectOptionsScreenshot', async t => {
    await faveDogs.load(t)
    await t
        .click(faveDogs.dogSelect)
        .hover(faveDogs.dogSelect.find('option').withText('German Shepherd')
        .takeScreenshot()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you faced an issue in the current product version. I've reproduced this behavior and we are going to look into it in the context of this thread created based on your information: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4101.